# Boost managed_windows_shared_memory find() crash

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I am trying to develop a dll plugin for a third party application which reads data generated by another exe. I am using `boost::managed_windows_shared_memory` for this.

The exe creates the shared memory and writes an object to it which is working fine. However, when I try to find that object in the dll code my the 3rd party app crashes. I searched a lot and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651878/how-do-i-debug-or-fix-the-endless-loop-and-heap-corruption-issue-involving-boost). The last answer mentions that using find() creates a deadlock.

I tried using `boost::interprocess_mutex` but it didn't work either. Any guidelines on how I can fix this? Thanks!

**In the exe:**

```
boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex myMutex;

myMutex.lock();

i = managed_shm.find_or_construct<int>("MyInteger")(992); 

myMutex.unlock();
```

**In the dll :**

```
boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex myMutex;

myMutex.lock();

std::pair<int*, std::size_t> p = managed_shm.find<int>("MyInteger"); 

myMutex.unlock();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interprocess (anonymous) is intended to used, when placed *inside* shared memory. If you want to use it to govern the creation of the shared-memory area or to synchronize the access to it *from outside the shared memory*, use a *named mutex*:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_named_example